Register new metadata file / snapshot for existing Iceberg table in catalog - Xtable
I am currently using the fairly new package called Apache Xtable which translates the metadata of one open table format (iceberg, hudi, delta) to the remaining two. This effectivly allows for interoperability between formats. Very useful.
But now I am going through implementation I am running into a problem when attempting to "refresh" an Iceberg table after an Xtable sync. By this I mean changing the current snapshot to an unregistered one within the Iceberg catalog and point Iceberg to the new metadata file.

I first make a Hudi table and make an upsert as to see commit history across formats for testing purposes
I then sync with XTable (run the jar)
java -jar /workspaces/Research/testing/xtable/xtable-utilities-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundled.jar --datasetConfig hudi_to_others.yaml
Then following the Xtable documentation, I create a new table.
CREATE SCHEMA iceberg_db;
CALL local.system.register_table( table => 'local.iceberg_db.test_data', metadata => '/workspaces/Research/testing/tmp/engine_test_data/metadata/v1.metadata.json' );
Executing this works and I now have a new iceberg table registered in the metastore. However after making a new upsert into the hudi table and making another Xtable sync the changes do not appear on the Iceberg side. This is because the iceberg catalog is pointing to the old metadata file and snapshot-id while a new working metadata file has been written by Xtable and is sitting in the directory but Iceberg seems to ignore it.

To fix this issue I have tried the following:

Editing the table properties and current-snapshot-id:
ALTER TABLE local.iceberg_db.test_data SET TBLPROPERTIES('metadata_location'='/workspaces/Research/testing/tmp/metadata/v2.metadata.json');
only to get
Cannot roll back to unknown snapshot id: 2374816410093529928

I have also tried registering the table again with the register_table function. Only to get a table already exists error.

Finally I have tried changing the version-hint.txt file to change where iceberg catalog looks for the current metadata file.


Right now the only working way I see to change the catalog is to register a new table and drop the old one which feels excessive and clunky. If this is a reasonable approach or there is another way, let me know.
